# Spring security, anonymous and authenticated for same endpoind

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have `/home` endpoind:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "msg", required = false)  String message{

            modelView.setViewName("landingpage/home");


        return modelView;
    }
```

it returns html that contains also login and also dashboard for logged users. So, for authenticated users, it is open:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/book/**").authenticated()
```

but also after failed login, it must be open because it throws message to /home endpoint:

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
....
     String exceptionMessage = exception.getMessage();
        String msgParam = "?msg=" + EncryptionUtil.encode(exceptionMessage);
        response.sendRedirect(/home + msgParam);
```

So what i want is, for

```
localhost:8080/home -> should be open to onlyauthenticated
localhost:8080/home?msg=asdsada -> should be open to all users
```

I tried to add this

```
  .antMatchers("/reset-password", "/login", "/home/**").anonymous()
```

So all class became like this:

```
        .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/deposit/**").authenticated()
         .antMatchers("/reset-password", "/login", "/home/**").anonymous()
```

but when i go to

http://localhost:8080/home?msg=BAcQreS-4_K54e3jWSksds

it cant go because  not allowed for nonauthenticated.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `regexMatchers` instead of `antMatchers`, `antMatchers` ignores the query string.

```
.regexMatchers("/home").authenticated()
.regexMatchers("/home?msg=.*").permitAll()
```

Comment: `           .regexMatchers("/home?msg=.*").anonymous()
                .regexMatchers("/home").permitAll()` i did like this. It works only when logged in. When logged it, home works. For anonyömous, `/home?msg` this does not work